# Quickly remove single quotes from CSV data loaded into a database

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a database built from CSV files loaded from an external source. For some reason, an ID number in many of the tables is loaded into the CSV / database encased in single quotes - here's a sample line:

```
 "'010010'","MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH","8000 ALABAMA HIGHWAY 69","","","GUNTERSVILLE","AL","35976","MARSHALL","2565718000","Acute Care Hospitals","Government - Hospital District or Authority","Yes"
```

Is there any SQL I can run on the already-established database to strip these single quotes, or do I have to parse every CSV file and re-import?

Comment: If it is a standard csv file then mysqlimport should have no problems handling this type of data.  What did you use to import the data?

Comment: Importing the data works fine, but the single quotes in the data make SELECTs inconvenient.

Comment: You need to find out why the external source puts the single quotes around that identifier.  Is this a one-off import or will you have to do it repeatedly?  If repeatedly, you need to try and get the supplied data fixed (though don't be surprised when they say "they can't").  If one-off, then try an update like BiggsTRC suggests.

Comment: Why would the original data have single quotes around it for an ID field?

Comment: It's from a government source, I'm as confused as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following would do it (test it first):

```
UPDATE U
SET YourID = REPLACE(YourID, '''', '')
FROM MyTable AS U
WHERE YourID LIKE '''%'''
```

If it works right, do a full backup before running it in production.

Comment: Maybe the LIKE clause should be `LIKE '''%'''` (search for an opening single quote, anything, a close single quote)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Good catch.  I updated my code to reflect this change.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi BiggsTRC - 

The final code I used was:

USE hospitals;
UPDATE hospitals
SET ProviderNumber = REPLACE(ProviderNumber, '''', '')
WHERE ProviderNumber LIKE '''%''';

This is just a slight modification of yours, I'm not sure what the extra code was for. Thanks!